# Time-dependent events in ODE

Tags: julia, ode

I recently started with Julia and wanted to implement one of my usual problems - implement time-depended events.

For now I have:

```
# Packages
using Plots
using DifferentialEquations

# Parameters
k21 = 0.14*24
k12 = 0.06*24
ke = 1.14*24
α = 0.5
β = 0.05
η = 0.477
μ = 0.218
k1 = 0.5
V1 = 6

# Time
maxtime = 10
tspan = (0.0, maxtime)

# Dose
stim = 100

# Initial conditions
x0 = [0 0 2e11 8e11]

# Model equations
function system(dy, y, p, t)
  dy[1] = k21*y[2] - (k12 + ke)*y[1]
  dy[2] = k12*y[1] - k21*y[2]
  dy[3] = (α - μ - η)*y[3] + β*y[4] - k1/V1*y[1]*y[3]
  dy[4] = μ*y[3] - β*y[4]
end

# Events
eventtimes = [2, 5]
function condition(y, t, integrator)
    t - eventtimes
end
function affect!(integrator)
    x0[1] = stim
end
cb = ContinuousCallback(condition, affect!)

# Solve
prob = ODEProblem(system, x0, tspan)
sol = solve(prob, Rodas4(), callback = cb)

# Plotting
plot(sol, layout = (2, 2))
```

But the output that is give is not correct. More specifically, the events are not taken into account and the initial condition doesn't seems to be `0` for `y1` but `stim`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`t - eventtimes` doesn't work because one's a scalar and the other is a vector. But for this case, it's much easier to just use a `DiscreteCallback`. When you make it a `DiscreteCallback` you should pre-set the stop times so that to it hits `2` and `5` for the callback. Here's an example:

```
# Packages
using Plots
using DifferentialEquations

# Parameters
k21 = 0.14*24
k12 = 0.06*24
ke = 1.14*24
α = 0.5
β = 0.05
η = 0.477
μ = 0.218
k1 = 0.5
V1 = 6

# Time
maxtime = 10
tspan = (0.0, maxtime)

# Dose
stim = 100

# Initial conditions
x0 = [0 0 2e11 8e11]

# Model equations
function system(dy, y, p, t)
  dy[1] = k21*y[2] - (k12 + ke)*y[1]
  dy[2] = k12*y[1] - k21*y[2]
  dy[3] = (α - μ - η)*y[3] + β*y[4] - k1/V1*y[1]*y[3]
  dy[4] = μ*y[3] - β*y[4]
end

# Events
eventtimes = [2.0, 5.0]
function condition(y, t, integrator)
    t ∈ eventtimes
end
function affect!(integrator)
    integrator.u[1] = stim
end
cb = DiscreteCallback(condition, affect!)

# Solve
prob = ODEProblem(system, x0, tspan)
sol = solve(prob, Rodas4(), callback = cb, tstops = eventtimes)

# Plotting
plot(sol, layout = (2, 2))
```

[image]

This avoids rootfinding altogether so it should be a much nicer solution that hacking time choices into a rootfinding system.

Either way, notice that the `affect` was changed to

```
function affect!(integrator)
    integrator.u[1] = stim
end
```

It needs to be modifying the current `u` value otherwise it won't do anything.